# Convergence of $ \left(1+ \frac{x} {n}\right )^{n^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, solution-verification, uniform-convergence, sequence-of-function

Consider the sequence of functions defined by
$$ f_n(x)= \left(1+ \frac{x} {n}\right )^{n^2}
$$ for $x \in [-1,0]$.
What can I say about the convergence?

My attempt

For every $n$, $f_n(0)=1$.
Then using the Taylor expression,
for every $x \in [-1,0)$
$$ \lim_{n \to +\infty} f_n (x) = \lim_{n \to +\infty} 
e^{\ln(\left(1+ \frac{x} {n}\right)^{n^2}) } = \lim_{n \to +\infty}  e^{n^2 \ln(\left(1+ \frac{x} {n}\right)) } = \lim_{n \to +\infty} e^{n^2 \frac{x} {n}} = 
\lim_{n \to +\infty} e^{nx} = 0
$$
We have a limit function which is not continuous, whereas every $f_n$ is continuous.
So we don't have uniform convergence.

I would like to be sure about it. Do you know other ways to solve the problem?
Thanks for your comments and hints.

("extra" curiosity: I was tempted to write down something like (*edited) $ f_n(x)= e^{xn} $. Is such a thing possible or completely wrong? )

Comment: This is correct, except from the writing $f_n(x)=e^{x^n}$ : indeed, you don't have $\left( 1+ \frac{x}{n}\right)^n = e^x$ !

Comment: Yes, I get it now. I hoped that this would be true at least for the limit in n or something like that. Maybe the exercise used this writing as a bait.

Comment: In standard notation, $e^{x^n}$ means $e^y$ where $y = x^n.$ That is very different from $(e^x)^n,$ which is how I might be tempted to rewrite $\left(1+ \frac{x} {n}\right )^{n^2}$. And indeed $(e^x)^n = e^{nx}.$

Comment: Yes, of course.